# Is it necceary to rethrow the CancellationException in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm following the "[Kotlin coroutine deep dive](https://leanpub.com/coroutines)" book to understand coroutine a bit further. I came across the below statement in the book which I can't understand clearly and would be helpful if someone explain me with a simple example.

> **CancellationException** can be caught using a try-catch, but it is
> recommended to rethrow it.

And he gave an example,

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

suspend fun main(): Unit = coroutineScope {
    val job = Job()
    launch(job) {
        try {
            repeat(1_000) { i ->
                delay(200)
                println("Printing $i")
            }
        } catch (e: CancellationException) {
            println(e)
            throw e
        }
    }
    delay(1100)
    job.cancelAndJoin()
    println("Cancelled successfully")
    delay(1000)
}
```

As you can see, it catches `catch (e: CancellationException)` and rethrow it, now I wonder **what happens if I don't rethrow it**. I commented out the `throw e` but the code executes as usual.

As I can see from [kotlin doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exception-handling.html#cancellation-and-exceptions), CancellationException is used for structured concurrency which means the CancellationException won't cancel the parent instead **it signals the parents to cancel all the other children of the parent** (Am I right here ?)

I believe that my understanding is wrong and the below code proves that,

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val parentJob = launch {
        launch {
            println("Starting child 1")
            delay(1000)
            throw CancellationException("Close other child under this parent")
        }
        launch {
            println("Starting child 2")
            delay(5000)
            println("This should not be printed, but getting printed. Don't know why?")
        }
        delay(2000)
        println("Parent coroutine completed")
    }
    parentJob.join()
}
```

As you see, I have created a `parentJob` and two child jobs inside then I terminate `child 1` by throwing `CancellationException` and expecting that parent has to cancel `child 2` but not.

Comment: Where did you get the information that cancelling a coroutine will cause all other siblings of it to be cancelled as well?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer: if you must catch a `CancellationException`, call `ensureActive` afterwards to ensure that the coroutine terminates.

This is a great question that is not easy to answer. There are two important points that will help to understand the explanation. I think these points explain why you are seeing behaviour that you don't expect in the code examples you have given.

1. Throwing a `CancellationException` *does not* cancel a coroutine.
2. Catching the `CancellationException` *does not* "un-cancel" the coroutine.

Cancellation exceptions are used as a "quick exit" mechanism to allow cancelled coroutines to stop what they're doing. However, the exception itself isn't what determines whether the coroutine is cancelled. That information is stored separately as part of the coroutine's `Job`.

If you have a cancelled coroutine that generates a cancellation exception, and you catch the exception and don't rethrow it, you can run into issues because the coroutine may not exit even after it's supposed to be cancelled.

Equally, if you throw a cancellation exception in a coroutine that has not been cancelled, you can run into a problem where the coroutine appears to exit silently, without errors, even though an exception was thrown.

I've written about this in detail in my article "[The Silent Killer That's Crashing Your Coroutines](https://medium.com/better-programming/the-silent-killer-thats-crashing-your-coroutines-9171d1e8f79b)."

My conclusion is that after catching a cancellation exception, the safest thing to do is not to rethrow it but to call `ensureActive` on the current coroutine context instead.

Comment: Can you explain why'd one want to catch a `CancellationException`, other than for academic purposes?

Comment: There are two main reasons that you might end up catching a `CancellationException`. The first is if you want to provide your own handling for all possible errors that might come from the code you're running. This is common in framework-level code, and typically means catching all possible exceptions and then choosing specific ones to rethrow. The second case is if you think that something other than coroutine cancellation might have caused a `CancellationException` to be thrown. This is much more common than you might think, and I gave some examples in my linked article.